# How to read the key3.db file?

Tags: encryption, passwords, web-browser, databases, firefox

The file `key3.db` contains the key that is used to encrypt the Firefox passwords stored in `logins.json` file.

I don't use master password in Firefox, but according to [this article](http://raidersec.blogspot.in/2013/06/how-browsers-store-your-passwords-and.html), my passwords are encrypted with a random key that is stored in `key3.db` file.

I tried to open the file using the SqliteBrowser, but I got an error: "Invalid file format". Can anyone know how to read this file so I will be able to get the key for my Firefox passwords?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If no master password is set, Firefox uses an empty password.

For a dirty Python script to decrypt and dump the data (plus some more), see the following code. It is an old project of mine and I just updated the reading of the passwords and usernames which were saved in `signons.sqlite` before (now in `logins.json`). I can't guarantee that (everything) is working, but it did in my test case.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from ctypes import *
import struct
import base64
import platform
import os
import sqlite3
import json

# TODO: if python 3. use
#from configParser import ConfigParser
# else
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser

#
# Some little firefox forensic script delivering following data:
# - saved passwords (decrypted if no master pw is set)
# - visited pages
# - download history
# - form history
# - cookies 
#
# TODO:
# - flash cookies and stuff
# - finish comments
# - add little brute forcer for master pw
# - dump master pw ?
# - add some more compatibility stuff (mac if requested, else fuck it)
# - use some user defined exceptions instead plain exception
# - cache
# - think about which data from the db to return ;)
#
# ATTENTION: On my win7 system i needed a newer sqlite version.
# see http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-tutor/96183/
# - easy (and dirty) solution: get new sqlite.dll, replace in ...python/DLLS/
#
# CREDITS:
# - Decrypt saved passwords: https://github.com/pradeep1288/ffpasscracker
# - Myself for doing a .schema on every db to get the structure *yay for me*
#


#Password structures for firefox >= 3.5 ?!
class SECItem(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('type',c_uint),('data',c_void_p),('len',c_uint)]
class secuPWData(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('source',c_ubyte),('data',c_char_p)]
(SECWouldBlock,SECFailure,SECSuccess)=(-2,-1,0)
(PW_NONE,PW_FROMFILE,PW_PLAINTEXT,PW_EXTERNAL)=(0,1,2,3)


class FileNotFoundException(Exception): pass



class Firefox_data_generic(object):
    """
    Some general informations:
    - Every timestamp is a unix timestamp in millisec (/1000 to use with pythons time stuff)
    - 
    """

    def __init__(self, profilpath = None, compatibility_infos = None ):
        if platform.system().lower() == 'windows':
            find_profil_path =  self.__find_profile_path_windows
            load_libraries = self.__load_libraries_win
        else: # TODO. care about mac (which i don't atm)
            find_profil_path = self.__find_profile_path_linux
            load_libraries = self.__load_libraries_linux

        if profilpath is None:
            self.profilpath = find_profil_path()
        else:
            self.profilpath = profilpath
        self.default_profil = self.__get_default_profile()

        if compatibility_infos is None:
            self.ff_version, self.platform_dir, self.app_dir = self._get_info_from__compatibility_ini()
        else:
            self.ff_version, self.platform_dir, self.app_dir = compatibility_infos

        load_libraries(*self.ff_version)

        # set up for the specified ff version
        major, minor = self.ff_version
        # We don' care about stone age ff versions
        if self.ff_version < (3, 5):
            raise Exception('Nobody got time for implementing the features for this fucking old ff version')
        # download history moved from downloads.sqlite to places.sqlite
        if major >= 26:
            self.get_all_downloads = self.__get_all_downloads_places
            print 'get downloads from places.sqlite'
        else:
            self.get_all_downloads = self.__get_all_downloads_downloads
            print 'get downloads from downloads.sqlite'


        #print 'Profilepath is:', self.profilpath

    #############################################################
    # Placeholder
    #############################################################
    def get_all_downloads(self, profile = None):
        """ returns [(url, fileName, saveTo, size, endTime, done), ...]
        monkey patched to __get_all_downloads_downloads for version < 26 (TODO: ?)
        or else to __get_all_downloads_places
        """
        raise NotImplementedError('get_all_downloads not implemented')


    #############################################################
    # General working functions
    #############################################################  
    def _get_info_from__compatibility_ini(self, profile = None):
        if profile is None:
            profile = self.default_profil
        config_file = '/'.join((profile, 'compatibility.ini'))
        if not os.path.isfile(config_file):
            raise FileNotFoundException('compatibility.ini not found at "%s"' % config_file)
        config = ConfigParser()
        config.read(config_file) # TODO: catch return (list of succesfully read configs)
        major, minor = config.get('Compatibility', 'LastVersion').split('_')[0].split('.')[:2]
        # TODO: check if value exists
        return ( (int(major), int(minor)), config.get('Compatibility', 'LastPlatformDir'), config.get('Compatibility', 'LastAppDir'))

    def get_all_visited(self, profile = None):
        """ Return all visited urls in the form of [(url, visit_count, last_visit_date), ...]
        Ordered by date asc.
        If no profile path is suplied use the default one.
        Should work from v. 3.0 and above (TODO: ?)
        """
        if profile is None:
            profile = self.default_profil
        db_path = '/'.join((profile, 'places.sqlite'))
        if not os.path.isfile(db_path):
            return None # TODO: raise exception
        con = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
        ret = con.execute('SELECT url, visit_count, last_visit_date FROM moz_places where visit_count > 0 order by last_visit_date asc;').fetchall()
        con.close()
        return ret

    def search_history(self, custom_filter, profile = None):
        for elem in self.get_all_visited(profile):
            if custom_filter(elem):
                yield elem      


    def test_master_pw(self, password, profile = None):
        if profile is None:
            profile = self.default_profil
        self.libnss.NSS_Init(profile) # TODO: check for errors here ? Init it once for all functions ?
        keySlot = self.libnss.PK11_GetInternalKeySlot()
        ret = self.libnss.PK11_CheckUserPassword( c_int(keySlot), c_char_p(password)) == SECSuccess
        self.libnss.PK11_FreeSlot(c_int(keySlot))
        self.libnss.NSS_Shutdown()
        return ret

    def is_master_password_set(self, profile = None):
        return not self.test_master_pw('', profile)




    def get_saved_passes(self, profilpath = None, decrypt = True, masterpass = ''):
        """ Try to get and decrypt saved passwords.
        The result (if successfuly) is in the form:[(hostname, httpRealm, formSubmitURL, usernameField, passwordField, username, password, encType, timeCreated, timeLastUsed, timePasswordChanged, timesUsed), ...]
        username and password are decrypted if no master password is set or they are not encrypted (doh) or the decrypt flag is set to False.
        In this cases the unaltered data is returned.
        """
        # decrypting part from https://github.com/pradeep1288/ffpasscracker 
        # for db schema: http://www.securityxploded.com/firepasswordviewer.php#for_firefox_3_5_and_above
        #  or just do a .schema moz_logins in the signons.sqlite /* signons.sqlite is gone and replaced by logins.json */
        if profilpath is None:
            profilpath = self.default_profil


        db_path = '/'.join((profilpath, 'logins.json'))
        if not os.path.isfile(db_path):
            raise FileNotFoundException('signons.sqlite not found at "%s"' % db_path)
        with open(db_path, 'rb') as fd:
            login_data = json.load(fd)

        # care about 'would_block' (-2) ?
        if self.libnss.NSS_Init(profilpath) != SECSuccess:
            # TODO: react to this
            print """Error Initalizing NSS_Init,\n
            propably no usefull results"""
            raise Exception('NSS_Init failed') # TODO: error code ?

        # TODO: check errors
        slot = self.libnss.PK11_GetInternalKeySlot()
        self.libnss.PK11_CheckUserPassword(slot, masterpass)
        self.libnss.PK11_Authenticate(slot, True, 0)

        pwdata = secuPWData()
        pwdata.source = PW_NONE
        pwdata.data=0

        uname = SECItem()
        passwd = SECItem()
        dectext = SECItem()
        con = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
        ret = list()
        for row in login_data['logins']:        
            if not decrypt: # not encrypted
                row["encryptedUsername"] = base64.b64decode(row["encryptedUsername"])
                row["encryptedPassword"] = base64.b64decode(row["encryptedPassword"])
                ret.append(row)
                continue
            # decrypt it                 
            uname.data  = cast(c_char_p(base64.b64decode(row["encryptedUsername"])),c_void_p)
            uname.len = len(base64.b64decode(row["encryptedUsername"]))
            passwd.data = cast(c_char_p(base64.b64decode(row["encryptedPassword"])),c_void_p)
            passwd.len=len(base64.b64decode(row["encryptedPassword"]))
            if self.libnss.PK11SDR_Decrypt(byref(uname),byref(dectext), 0)==-1:
                raise Exception('Username decrypt exception with:' + str(row))
            row["encryptedUsername"] = string_at(dectext.data,dectext.len)
            if self.libnss.PK11SDR_Decrypt(byref(passwd),byref(dectext), 0)==-1:
                raise Exception('Password decrypt exception with:' + str(row))
            row["encryptedPassword"] = string_at(dectext.data, dectext.len)
            ret.append(row)
        self.libnss.NSS_Shutdown()
        con.close()
        return ret

    def get_all_cookies(self, profile = None): # yummy
        """ Returns all cookies in the form of [(baseDomain, appId, inBrowserElement, name, value, host, path, expiry, lastAccessed, creationTime, isSecure, isHttpOnly), ...]
        Should work for versions >= 3.0 (TODO: ?)
        """
        if profile is None:
            profile = self.default_profil
        db_path = '/'.join((profile, 'cookies.sqlite'))
        con = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
        ret = con.execute('SELECT baseDomain, appId, inBrowserElement, name, value, host, path, expiry, lastAccessed, creationTime, isSecure, isHttpOnly FROM moz_cookies;').fetchall()
        con.close()
        return ret

    def get_all_form_history(self, profile = None, orderBy = 'firstUsed', orderASC = False):
        """ Returns all form history in the for of: [(fieldname, value, timesUsed, firstUsed, lastUsed), ...]
        Should work for versions >= 3.0 (TODO: ?)
        """
        if profile is None:
            profile = self.default_profil
        db_path = '/'.join((profile, 'formhistory.sqlite'))
        con = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
        ret = con.execute('SELECT fieldname, value, timesUsed, firstUsed, lastUsed from moz_formhistory order by %s %s;' % (orderBy, ('ASC' if orderASC else 'DESC'))).fetchall()
        con.close()
        return ret

    def search_form_history(self, custom_filter, profile = None, orderBy = 'firstUsed', orderASC = False):
        for elem in self.get_all_form_history(profile, orderBy, orderASC):
            if custom_filter(elem):
                yield elem 

    #############################################################
    # Version and platform specific functions
    #############################################################
    def __find_profile_path_windows(self):
        """ Should work for win >= 2000 (TODO: ?)
        """
        # TODO: should work for Windows 2000, XP, Vista, and Windows 7, (win 8 TODO: ?)
        path = '/'.join((os.environ['APPDATA'], 'Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles'))
        if not os.path.isdir(path):
            raise FileNotFoundException('Profile folder "%s" not found.' % path)
        return path

    def __find_profile_path_linux(self):
        # TODO: check where the default profile path on different distros are
        path = '/'.join((os.environ['HOME'], '.mozilla/firefox'))
        if not os.path.isdir(path):
            raise FileNotFoundException('Profile folder "%s" not found.' % path)
        return path

    def __get_default_profile(self):
        try:
            profile = ( p for p in os.listdir(self.profilpath) if p.endswith('.default') and os.path.isdir('/'.join((self.profilpath, p)))  ).next()
            return '/'.join((self.profilpath, profile))
        except StopIteration:
            return None

    def __load_libraries_win(self, major, minor):
        #TODO: check relevant version changes
        os.environ['PATH'] = ';'.join([self.platform_dir, os.environ['PATH']])
        self.libnss = CDLL('/'.join((self.platform_dir, "nss3.dll")))

    def __load_libraries_linux(self, major, minor):
        #TODO: check relevant version changes
        #TODO: could that lib be somewhere else (not in path) ? (i.e: is this safe ?)
        self.libnss = CDLL("libnss3.so")

    def __get_all_downloads_downloads(self, profile = None):       
        #TODO: untested but should work
        if profile is None:
            profile = self.default_profil
        db_path = '/'.join((profile, 'downloads.sqlite'))
        con = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
        ret = con.execute('SELECT source, name, target, maxBytes, endTime, state FROM moz_downloads;').fetchall()
        con.close()
        return ret

    def __get_all_downloads_places(self, profile = None):
        if profile is None:
            profile = self.default_profil
        db_path = '/'.join((profile, 'places.sqlite'))
        con = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
        ret = list()
        for download in con.execute("""SELECT url, a.content, b.content, c.content from moz_annos a, moz_annos b, moz_annos c, moz_places p
            where a.place_id = b.place_id and b.place_id = c.place_id and p.id = a.place_id
            and a.anno_attribute_id = (select id from moz_anno_attributes where name = 'downloads/destinationFileName')
            and b.anno_attribute_id = (select id from moz_anno_attributes where name = 'downloads/destinationFileURI')
            and c.anno_attribute_id = (select id from moz_anno_attributes where name = 'downloads/metaData');
        """).fetchall():
            values = json.loads(download[3])
            ret.append( (download[0], download[1], download[2], values['fileSize'], values['endTime'], values['state']) )
        con.close()       
        return ret







if __name__ == '__main__':
    profile = "C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/FF_PROFILE"
    ff = Firefox_data_generic()
    print 'version and paths:'
    print ff._get_info_from__compatibility_ini()

    print 'Master password is set:', ff.is_master_password_set(profile=profile) 

    print "Test some password", ff.test_master_pw('test1234567')

    print 'passwords:'
    print ff.get_saved_passes(profilpath=profile, decrypt=True, masterpass="")

    print 'cookies:'
    print ff.get_all_cookies()

    #print 'form history:'    
    #print ff.get_all_form_history(orderBy='name', True)
    print 'form history from search bar:'
    print list(ff.search_form_history(lambda x: 'searchbar' in x[0]))

    #print 'visited sites:'    
    #print ff.get_all_visited()
    print 'visited sites with login in url:'
    print list(ff.search_history(lambda x: 'login' in x[0]))

    print 'downloads:'
    print ff.get_all_downloads()
```

**It should work on Windows and Linux, but I just tested the changes on a Windows system.**

Edit: I replaced the script to crack the passwords with one to just dump different information (including the passwords and usernames in decrypted form with a given password)

Answer (score 7):

**Guide to decrypt Firefox's saved passwords database**

1. `git clone https://github.com/unode/firefox_decrypt.git`
2. `cd firefox_decrypt`
3. `python firefox_decrypt.py`
4. Enter Master Password if you have one, or just press enter
5. Enjoy

Or you can also use https://www.dumpzilla.org/

Comment: This is the only solution I've seen that works with recent Firefox (key4.db, cert9.db, etc). WARNING: **one should review the program before running it**, and/or **run it in a way that disables network access**. Suggestion with Linux: `unshare -n python firefox_decrypt.py`

Comment: @HuguesM. Great warning, but it's harder than you think to prevent network access: you'd need to run it from a computer which never has network access again after it runs, because the program could register another program to start up and wait for network access, even across reboots. Easiest way would be with a virtual machine which never has network access, and which is destroyed after performing the operation.

Comment: firefox_decrypt.py was also the only thing I found that worked for Thunderbird.

Answer (score 1):

**use the db_dump185 command from libdb-utils (rhel-based) or libdb1-compat (debian based) package**

I know this is an old question but I have been researching this myself and wanted an answer to the question and not a workaround.

The reason this was so difficult is because this key3.db file is actually a much older version of the berkeley database that the regular db_dump command cannot read.  It was not immediately obvious that in order to read this version 1.85 package I would need to use the nearly-identical db_dump185 command instead.  I ran around in circles trying to re-compile with the --enable-dump185 option when all along the OS package contained that but required a separate command to take advantage of.

Now that I have that DB open, I'm still not sure what to do with the data inside, which seems to be the same problem that [Command line tools to decrypt my Firefox 45.7.0 passwords using key3.db and logins.json?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/152285/command-line-tools-to-decrypt-my-firefox-45-7-0-passwords-using-key3-db-and-logi) is having as well.  I think my current solution will be to not use (cert8|key3).db and instead move to the (cert9|key4).db instead, as it appears sqlite3 was able to open key4.db without any further fuss.  It seems that the metadata table in key4.db contains item1 and item2 records, which I'm assuming are indeed the key and IV needed to encrypt/decrypt values into/out of logins.json, but I'm still not sure how to put that all together at this point.

Hopefully if I'm not able to figure this out myself this info can help lead someone else to an answer that is following the current rabbit hole that I'm following right now.